# saying request for "one success after another"

Tags: phrase-request, proverbs

Is there a saying to the effect that when a person has a sucess, another soon follows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **on a roll** ([thefreedictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+a+roll))
> *in the midst of a series of successes*

There's also the equivalent (but somewhat less "slangy") [**winning streak**.](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/winning-streak)

Comment: What about "Nothing succeeds like success"?

Comment: Even just [*I'm on a roll*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Nothing+succeeds+like+success%2CI%27m+on+a+roll&year_start=1980&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) is now far more common than *Nothing succeeds like success*. Allowing for Past Tense and different subjects, the "roll" idiom will be *vastly* more common than the "quirky saying". But I'd also say that *usually*, the quirky saying refers to being ***predictably*** "socially" successful (the rich get richer, because that really is how "the system" works), whereas being "on a roll" is usually just a matter of blind chance.

Answer (score -1):

[It never rains but it pours](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/it+never+rains+but+it+pours) means pretty much exactly what you want. I've heard it most often refer to bad things, but The Free Dictionary says it can be used to refer to good things as well.

The construction is a bit archaic; read it as "The only time it rains is when it's a downpour."

Comment: I suggest this idiom is almost *never* used of *good* things. I see no reference to that possibility in Merriam-Webster or Collins, for example.